# PythonでURLのリスト分割してから全てのURLを繰り返す方法

Tags: python, python3

seleniumを使って、 [駐車場一覧NAVITIME](https://www.navitime.co.jp/category/0805/13227/)のwebサイトから各ページのURLを抽出して
spotのみのURL取得したいです。

**現在の結果**
❶からURLを取得してから、❷spotのみのURL取得したいです。

❶while文から各ページ1,2,3,4...のURL取得
　各ページがありますので、URLは分割されてリストで表示されます。

```
['https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60012-55019091', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0044576', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0011524', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0036667', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0045563', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0011405', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60012-55027976', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60048-310002727', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60048-310012280', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0031689', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0046029', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0049279', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0053461', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0055195', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0059337']
4
['https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0013367', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0059411', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0007349', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0014044', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0017340', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0019251', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0021939', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0024783', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0024801', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0025235', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60014-734-3', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60018-A1583', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60036-87905', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60036-88101', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60036-91194']
6
['https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-28734', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-29371', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-1003', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60036-92084', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60038-0181', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60079-NRP00562', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60079-NRP00674', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60004-CTR00249', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60004-CTR00286', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60004-NTMR0486', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60004-SPT00021', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60071-1130522', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-28733', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-38930', 'https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-38935']
8
['https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-52478']
```

❷spotのURLのみ取得

```
https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-52478
```

**実現したい内容**

❷spotのURLのみ取得
❶で分割されている各ページのリストを結合して、下記のように
繰り返しながら1ページのURLから最後の4ページのURLまで開きたいです。

```
https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60012-55019091
https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60001-BUK0044576
https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60007-REP0011524
・
・
・
・
https://www.navitime.co.jp/poi?spot=60034-52478
```

下記のコードで行いましたが、
どのように各ページのリスト結合すれば良いか。まだ分からない状態です。

while文の中に全て繰り返してやった方が良いでしょうか。

それともリスト分割したもの結合させた方が良いでしょうか。

while文の中にtry catchして入れていますが、
もし他の方法で各ページのULRを繰り返す方法ありましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

コード

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Condition
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import random
import subprocess


#headless background
option = Options()
#backgrand
#option.add_argument('--headless')

#ログイン情報を維持するための設定　
# 参考→https://rabbitfoot.xyz/selenium-chrome-profile
PROFILE_PATH ="C:\\Users\\users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" # 変更
option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + PROFILE_PATH)
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
#Getting Default Adapter failed error message
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install() ,options=option)

#駐車場一覧 - NAVITIME URL
URL= "https://www.navitime.co.jp/category/0805/13227/"

# URLを開く。
driver.get(URL)

#待機時間
time.sleep(2)
i=2
#while文から各ページ1,2,3,4...のURL取得
while True:
 try:
    
    #全てのURLを取得
    elements = driver.find_elements('xpath',"//a[@href]")
    #print(elements)

    new_list = []  #### 空のリストを定義して初期化
    for element in elements:
      list=element.get_attribute("href")

      #URLをリストとして作成
      data_list = list.splitlines()
      #print(data_list)

      #URLに含んでいるspot=URLのみ　出力
      l_in = [s for s in data_list if 'spot=' in s]
      #print(l_in)

      #spotを取得
      if l_in:
       new_list.append(l_in[0])  #### ループ内ではリストに追加するだけ

    print(new_list)

    #待機時間
    time.sleep(2)

   #次のボタンクリック
    button = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="body-left"]/ul[1]/li['+str(i)+']/a')
    button.click()

    #ページ数
    i=2+i
    print(i)

 except NoSuchElementException:
   break


#待機時間
time.sleep(3)

#取得したリストから1個ずつspot URLを開く
for item in new_list:
    
    #spot URL
    URL=item
    print(URL)

    # spot URLを開く。
    driver.get(URL)
    
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True:`のループ内で`new_list = []`を行っているためにそのような状況になっていますね。

該当箇所を以下のように変更すればできるでしょう。(前後は省略します)

```
#待機時間
time.sleep(2)
i=2
new_list = []  #### ←←←ここに移動する
#while文から各ページ1,2,3,4...のURL取得
while True:
 try:
    
    #全てのURLを取得
    elements = driver.find_elements('xpath',"//a[@href]")
    #print(elements)

    #### →→→削除またはコメントアウトする new_list = []  #### 空のリストを定義して初期化
    for element in elements:
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法で問題なくできました。While文の中では外にリストを出すことが勉強になりました。ちなみにWhile文の中でつ次のページをクリックする箇所trycathを使ってやっていますが、if分岐でも同じことできますか。

Comment: ちょっと検索した程度では見つからないので方法は無いか難しいのだと思われます。

Comment: はい、コメントありがとうございます。